# Permission denied while mounting samba cifs share on linux

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba, cifs

I have a samba server set up on a Linux computer that uses winbind on an AD domain. Everything seems to be working but I haven't been able to mount a samba share on another machine. Right now, I would just like to mount my home directory in a folder on another linux machine.

When I do:

```
smbclient -L mycomputer -U myuser
```

It asks for my password and I authenticate fine. It then lists my home directory as a share:

```
# smbclient -L mycomputer -U myuser
Enter myuser's password:
Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.9-151.el6]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server Version 3.6.9-151.el6)
    myuser          Disk      Home Directories

Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.9-151.el6]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

However, when I try to mount the share and enter my password, I get this:

```
mount -t cifs //mycomputer/myuser /mnt/cifs -o username=myuser,domain=MYDOMAIN
Password:
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations for the -o parameters like MYDOMAIN/myuser, putting MYDOMAIN.COM, etc. but it just doesn't seem to make any difference.

My samba config for these shares is as follows:

```
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = no
    writable = yes
    valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S
```

Can someone please provide some insight as to why I cannot mount this share? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I figured that I should add that I tried to mount the share on Windows as well as Mac OSX and it isn't mounting on either. I couldn't get exactly what the error was on OSX as it just gave me a "check with your system administrator" message. I would assume this means it is an issue with the server config, but what?

Comment: I cannot remember if it was the same error message, but after struggling very hard to get a windows share mounted via cifs it turned out that I needed only another option: `iocharset=utf8`, which seemed to have nothing to do with the error. Perhaps it's worth a try...

Comment: seemed plausible but that didn't do it :(

Comment: Can you browse/mount the share on the same machine on which the share exists? (Start->Run-> "\\mycomputer\myuser")

Comment: No, I am not able to mount it on the server machine either. I'd like to point out that I'm serving the share from samba on Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding path info to your homes:

```
path = /PathToHomesHome/%u
# like:
path = /home/%u
```

And if possible try without `valid users` restrictions.

And if smb is running as a different user remember that the directories in full path to your "home" will need to have at least `+x` for the samba user (depending on your setup, could require it for `other o+x`

On server you can also run `testparm` to see your setup.

To debug local `mount.cifs` try first

```
smbclient //mycomputer/myuser -U myuser
```